# How to detect a new iBeacon?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I range beacons and display them in my TableView. I need to detect when my app detects a new beacon. I try to do it in this way, but something goes wrong

```
var oldBeacons: [CLBeacon] = []

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
  for beacon in beacons {
    for oldBeacon in oldBeacons {
      if beacon.minor != oldBeacon.minor, beacon.major != oldBeacon.major {
        print("New Beacon")
      } else {
        print("Old Beacon")
      }
    }
  }
  oldBeacons = beacons
}
```

Comment: What does "Something goes wrong" mean?

Comment: @JustSid it means my app doesn't what I need. It detects an old beacon as a new beacon sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through two arrays won't easily work because if you ever see two beacons at the same time, you'll incorrectly think they are "new" because one is not the same as the other.

I typically use a Set to do this:

```
var detectedBeacons: Set<String>

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
  for beacon in beacons {
    let key = "\(beacon.proximityUUID) \(beacon.major) \(beacon.minor)"
    if detectedBeacons.contains(key) {
      print("Old Beacon")
    }
    else {
      print("New Beacon")
      detectedBeacons.insert(key)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But what if I detect a beacon, then turn it off and then again detect the beacon? I mean in the case I need to display that beacon as a new beacon.

Comment: Well, it comes down to how you define a new beacon.   A more sophisticated approach would be to use a Dictionary instead of a Set and track a timestamp of how long since the last beacon was seen.  Then you could make it configurable as to how long one could drop out from being seen before being considered a new beacon again.